# How to compare usernames in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, comparison, operators

I am trying to show a message based on user names in WordPress.
The code I am using:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if( 'user1' && 'user2' == $current_user->user_login ){
    echo "discount 20%";
}
else {
    echo "you could save 20% if you are a VIP customer";
}
```

If I use the above code with `&&` operator `discount 20%` is shown only to `user2`

If I use the above code with `||` operator `discount 20%` is shown to all the users even if the user is not logged in.

Code with `||`

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if( 'user1' || 'user2' == $current_user->user_login ){
   echo "discount 20%";
}
else {
   echo "you could save 20% if you are a VIP customer";
}
```

I will be adding usernames continuously in time.
discount 20% should be displayed only the usernames I will be adding. 
It should not displayed to other or guest/non-logged in users.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `'user1' == $current_user->user_login || 'user2' == $current_user->user_login`

Comment: Would it be better (if possible) to have some flag on the user to say they are a VIP?  Comparing user names seems a bit limiting.

Comment: try if $current_user == $current_user->user_login

Comment: As @NigelRen's suggested a user flag of some kind would be more scaleable. Why not create a new role for VIP customers? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding usernames in future, the following code will be useful.

```
// List of VIP usernames.
$vip_usernames = array(
    'user1',
    'user2'
);

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// Check if the username is in VIP usernames array.
if ( in_array( $current_user->user_login, $vip_usernames, true ) ) {
    echo "discount 20%";

} else {
    echo "you could save 20% if you are a VIP customer";
}
```